# Vue data property doesn't update when put inside <code> tag

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

My component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <select v-model="minecraftVersion">
      <option
        v-for="version in minecraftVersions"
        :key="version.version"
        :value="version.version"
      >{{version.version}}</option>
    </select>

    <code>
        dependencies {
          minecraft "com.mojang:minecraft:{{minecraftVersion}}"
          mappings "net.fabricmc:yarn:{{yarnVersion}}:v2"
          modImplementation "net.fabricmc:fabric-loader:{{loaderVersion}}"
          modImplementation "{{fabricMaven}}{{fabricVersion}}"
        }
    </code>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import stripIndent from "strip-indent";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      minecraftVersions: [],
      minecraftVersion: "<minecraftVersion>",
      yarnVersion: "<yarnVersion>",
      loaderVersion: "<loaderVersion>",
      fabricMaven: "<fabricMaven>",
      fabricVersion: "<fabricVersion>"
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$el.querySelectorAll("code").forEach(code => {
      code.innerHTML = stripIndent(code.innerHTML);
    });

    fetch("https://meta.fabricmc.net/v2/versions/game")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.minecraftVersions = data);

    let hash = this.$route.hash.substr(1).split("-");
    if (hash[0] == "version") {
      this.minecraftVersion = hash.slice(1).join("-");
    } else {
      for (let version of this.minecraftVersions) {
        if (version.stable) {
          this.minecraftVersion = version.version;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    minecraftVersion(newVersion, oldVersion) {
      if (oldVersion != "<minecraftVersion>") {
        this.$router.replace({ hash: "#version-" + newVersion });
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Data fetches fine, but all {{mustache}} props inside `<code>` don't react to changes. They are displayed as if they weren't changed. When putting outside `<code>`, all props work as intended.

P.S. Also when choosing a version with a hyphen it throws `SyntaxError: Document.querySelector: '#version-1.16-pre2' is not a valid selector`, yet continues to work as intended

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll()` interfered somehow. Deleting it helps